# Invalid JSON response (Codeigniter framework)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have created an Insert modal form with ajax. The insert works however, the validation is not working so any errors or sweet alert do not shows. I have a problem before when it comes to ajax.reload but when I solved it using answers from stackoverflow, the page automatically reloads after a successful insert or an invalid insert (database error). I am now trying to work on figuring out why. The console log for (data) in ajax part returns true. But it doesn't remain in the console because I think the page reloads. I also tried removing the ajax.reload() part but nothing happens. It just reloads even when I removed it.

## Update # 1 (New problem)

I did what jaromanda recommended using e.preventDefault() However, my problem before resurfaced. Ajax.reload doesn't work and it says "jquery.dataTables.min.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null"

## This is my ajax and controller codes:

```js
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {

        var supp_code = $('#supp_code').val();
        var address1 = $('#address1').val();
        var address2 = $('#address2').val();
        var country = $('#country').val();
        var description = $('#description').val();
        var tel_num = $('#tel_num').val();
        var fax_num = $('#fax_num').val();
        var contact_person = $('#contact_person').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var consol_agent = $('#consol_agent').val();
        var disc1 = $('#disc1').val();
        var disc2 = $('#disc2').val();
        var disc3 = $('#disc3').val();
        var disc4 = $('#disc4').val();
        var disc5 = $('#disc5').val();
        var last_transaction = $('#last_transaction').val();
        var old_supplier = $('#old_supplier').val();

        var sfm_table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();



        // var validate_form = validate_inquiry_form(first_name,email_id);
        // if(validate_form == true){
        $.ajax({

            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>SFM/insert',
            type: 'post',

            data: {
                'supp_code': supp_code,
                'address1': address1,
                'address2': address2,
                'country': country,
                'description': description,
                'tel_num': tel_num,
                'fax_num': fax_num,
                'contact_person': contact_person,
                'email': email,
                'consol_agent': consol_agent,
                'disc1': disc1,
                'disc2': disc2,
                'disc3': disc3,
                'disc4': disc4,
                'disc5': disc5,
                'last_transaction': last_transaction,
                'old_supplier': old_supplier
                
            },


            success: function(data) {

  
                if (data) {
                    
                    sfm_table.ajax.reload()

                    $("#sfm_modal").modal('hide');

                    swal("Data Inserted", {
                        icon: "success"
                    });



                } else {


                    swal("Error", {
                        icon: "error"
                    });

       
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
function insert()
 {

  

   $data1 = array(
       'SUPP_CODE'=> $this->input->post('supp_code'),
       'ADDRESS'=> $this->input->post('address1'),
       'ADDRESS2'=> $this->input->post('address2'),
       'COUNTRY'=> $this->input->post('country'),
       'DESCRIPTION'=> $this->input->post('description'),
       'TEL_NO'=> $this->input->post('tel_num'),
       'FAX_NO'=> $this->input->post('fax_num'),
       'CONTACT'=> $this->input->post('contact_person'),
       'EMAIL'=> $this->input->post('email'),
       'CONS_AGENT'=> $this->input->post('consol_agent'),
       'DISC1'=> $this->input->post('disc1'),
       'DISC2'=> $this->input->post('disc2'),
       'DISC3'=> $this->input->post('disc3'),
       'DISC4'=> $this->input->post('disc4'),
       'DISC5'=> $this->input->post('disc5'),
       'LAST_TRANS'=> $this->input->post('last_transaction'),
       'SUPP_CODE2'=> $this->input->post('old_supplier')
     );

 
     
    
    

    
     $insertReturn = $this->system_model->insert('fo_supp', $data1);
  

  
  
  echo json_encode( $insertReturn);

 }
```

## View:

```html
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="x_panel">
            <div class="x_title">
                <h2>Supplier Master File

                    <small></small>
                </h2>
                <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li>
                        <a class="collapse-link">
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
       <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
      </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Settings 1
                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Settings 2
                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="x_content">
                <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sfm_modal" style="float: right;">
     <i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i>
     <span>Add New Data</span>
    
   </button>
                </div>
                <table id="datatable-buttons" name="sfm_table"  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Supplier Code
                            </th>
                            <th>Address
                            </th>
                            <th>Country
                            </th>
                            <th>Description
                            </th>
                            <th>Telephone Number
                            </th>
                            <th>Fax Number
                            </th>
                            <th>Contact Person
                            </th>
                            <th>Email
                            </th>

                            <th>Actions
                            </th>
                            <th>Consolidating Agent
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 1
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 2
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 3
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 4
                            </th>
                            <th>Discount 5
                            </th>
                            <th>Last Transaction
                            </th>
                            <th>Old Supplier
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php if(!empty($fo_supp)): ?>
                        <?php foreach($fo_supp as $supp): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->SUPP_CODE?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->ADDRESS." ".$supp->ADDRESS2?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->COUNTRY?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DESCRIPTION?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->TEL_NO?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->FAX_NO?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->CONTACT?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->EMAIL?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
            
                                <a href="#sfm_modal_edit"  data-target="#sfm_modal_edit" id='<?=$supp->SUPP_CODE?>' class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
          <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i>
         </a>

        
                                <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal">
          <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i>
         </a>
                            </td>
      
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->CONS_AGENT?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC1?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC2?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC3?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC4?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->DISC5?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=  $supp->LAST_TRANS ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?=$supp->SUPP_CODE2?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++): ?>
                            <td>
                                <span class="text-danger"> Not Available </span>
                            </td>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!--MODAL HERE-->
        <div class="modal fade" name="sfm_modal " id="sfm_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            Create New Supplier
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal Body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                <!-- left column -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Supplier Code</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Supplier Code</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="supp_code" id="supp_code" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '999999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Address</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Address</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="address1" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Address 2</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Address 2</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="address2" class="form-control  col-md-10" id="address2" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Country</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Country</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control col-md-10" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="form-group"><label for="new_zip" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style = "visibility: hidden;">Description</label><span class="label label-default" >Supplier Code</span><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-sm-7"><label for="new_zip_detail" class="sr-only" style = "visibility: hidden;">City, State Country</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="new_zip_detail" placeholder="City, State Country" disabled=""></div></div> -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Description</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Description</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Telephone Number</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Telephone Number</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel_num" id="tel_num" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Fax Number</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Fax Number</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fax_num" id="fax_num" data-inputmask="'mask' : '(999) 999-9999'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Consolidating Agent</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Consolidating Agent</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" name="consol_agent" class="form-control" id="consol_agent" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 
                                </div>
                                <!-- right column -->
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Email</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Email</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Contact Person</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Contact Person</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_person" id="contact_person" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_subname" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 1</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 1</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc1" id="disc1" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_address" class="col-sm-2 control-label bg-danger" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 2</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 2</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc2" id="disc2" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_addresssub" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 3</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 3</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disc3" id="disc3" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 4</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 4</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc4" id="disc4" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Discount 5</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Discount 5</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="disc5" id="disc5" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Last Transaction</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Last Transaction</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_transaction" id="last_transaction" data-inputmask="'mask': '9999/99/99'">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="new_phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="visibility: hidden;">Old Supplier</label>
                                        <span class="label label-default">Old Supplier</span>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="old_supplier" id="old_supplier" placeholder="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                    </div>
                    <!-- End main input boxes, starting a new "row" -->
                    <!-- Modal Footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="newConsigneeReset">Reset</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Modal Footer -->
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- End modal body div -->
            </div>
            <!-- End modal content div -->
        </div>
        <!-- End modal dialog div -->
    </div>
    <!-- End modal div -->

<!-- /page content -->
```

Comment: because a form submit has a default action, one usually prevents this default action using `e.preventDefault()` in the submit handler

Comment: @JaromandaX If I do that the ajax.reload() doesn't work anymore. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: ajax.reload() isn't working period, when you are not preventing default it is essentially reloading the page. the `reload()` function only works when the reference object `sfm_table` has an ajax instance https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() otherwise where is this new data coming from? dt doesn't know that you just added something and want it to appear in the table. consider using https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html ... this is to say if i understand you correctly and you want the new item to be added to the table entirely with ajax.